# ViewPager setting currentItem loads Fragment twice

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment, android-viewpager2

When i set ViewPager current item manually from grater then 0 then ViewPager calls fragment onResume method 2 times i.e. 1st for 0 position then for that particular position

I want to load Fragment only single time i.e. for that particular position and not for 0 position

How to resolve this?

Thanks in Advance!

```
    pagerAdapter = BaseViewPagerAdapter(
        supportFragmentManager,
        mFragments,
        arrayListOf()
    )
    mBinding.viewPager.adapter = pagerAdapter
    mBinding.viewPager.setPageTransformer(
        true,
        CubeOutTransformer()
    )
    mBinding.viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(object : StoryPageChangeListener() {
        override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
            super.onPageSelected(position)
            currentPage = position
        }

        override fun onPageScrollCanceled() {
            currentFragment()?.resumeCurrentStory()
        }

    })
    if (pos > 0) {
        mBinding.viewPager.setCurrentItem(pos, false)
    }
```

Comment: You need to show your code of how you setup viewpager for anybody to be able to help.

Comment: Hi @Andrew Please check now i've edited the question